# Batch file: only process files with certain beginning and exclude them when they have certain endings

Tags: batch-file

I want to run tests with this batch file. All tests (input files) start with "Test" and the output file is named after the input file plus "_out". After researching, I added the if-statement, but it does not work.
With this version of the batch file, every output file is also processed (e.g. IN=Test_1_out OUT=Test_1_out_out) and I don't want that.

How do I stop files ending in "_out" from being processed?

```
@echo off

SET PROG_PATH=..\bin\Raetsel.exe

SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

FOR %%f IN (Test*) DO (
    SET IN=%%f
    SET OUT=%%f_out

    if %IN:~-4% neq "_out" (
        CALL %PROG_PATH% !IN! !OUT!
           IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 (
               ECHO success.
            )
        )
    )
)
PAUSE
```

Comment: you'll need [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)

Comment: I have set it to ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION. The problem is that the if statement does not work. I don't want the executable to be called if the infile ends with "_out".

Comment: You turned delayed expansion on, but you aren't using it. You need to say `if !IN:~-4! neq "_out"`

Comment: I also had to delete the quotation marks. Thanks to both of you!

Comment: You mean the quotes around `_out` in the `if` statement? I recommend to do the other way round and add them to the other comparison expression; otherwise you may run into troubles when `IN` is empty (I know, in this particular case `IN` will never be empty, but in general, using quotes for comparison expressions is best practice, unless you do numeric comparisons like `if %NUM% EQU 1`)...